# git clone command line is not working for a repo on github

Tags: python, git, github, clone

I am following the instructions of a code on Github. the first step is saying
Open a terminal, switch to the ANNA-PALM source code folder.
Then there is this command line

```
git clone https://github.com/imodpasteur/ANNA-PALM
cd ANNA-PALM
```

When I ran it on spyder (in anaconda) I get this error

```
File "<ipython-input-24-b04c1bbc8ffc>", line 1
  git clone https://github.com/imodpasteur/ANNA-PALM
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That's not Python code. You're running UNIX/Linux/Windows terminal/console commands in a Python interpreter. You have to run it in a terminal or command prompt.

Comment: That's command line syntax, not python. Use a terminal to check out the repo.

Comment: Thanks, I tried on command prompt but got this error

Comment: 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Is git installed on your system?

Comment: @user14492868 you have to install git to be able to use git...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is supposed to be run in terminal/cmd **not** python shell

1. open file explorer in the directory that you wish to add the cloned repository
2. enter cmd into directory bar
3. in cmd enter:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/imodpasteur/ANNA-PALM
   cd ANNA-PALM
   ```

Comment: Unfortunately, I got the same error

Comment: is git installed?

Comment: what happens if you enter                   "git --version"

Comment: I did not know I should instal git first. I installed it and it is working now. Thanks:)

Comment: you are very welcome